Automasking-like bug when sculpting?
I started diving into sculpting in Blender, and everything was feeling pretty good. Started getting used to the hotkeys and the general feel. I then took a break and left my computer with Blender running, and when I came back and continued sculpting, suddenly I get this strange artifacting when sculpting on certain parts of the mesh when doing nothing different than I was earlier.
You can see in the first picture a generally smooth base for this example. I then use clay strips over the chest, shoulder and collar bone areas and there are strong divots. Then I run the smooth brush over them and it smooths the strips but the divots are now pronounced. (I don't know if it's related to the issue, but you can see the highlighted outline of the mesh, because the smoothed version wouldn't show up in a viewport render while in sculpt mode, so I had to go into object mode to get the viewport render for that one)



I then ran the masking brush over the affected areas and the same areas are unaffected by the masking brush the same way as the sculpting brushes. I made sure the use the mouse when painting the mask to make sure it had full effect with full strength.

My attempts to solve this:
I have looked online and was not able to find anyone else talking about this issue.
Went into edit mode and recalculate normals (and applied scale and rotation just in case), checked the auto masking settings under the brush settings in the tools tab/panel.
Restarted blender multiple times.
Remesh didn't fix it. Changing remesh to a lower resolution and then remesh preserves this error at those lower resolutions.
So somehow after walking away and leaving Blender running for a while it's seemingly corrupted the mesh? And kept that corruption in the saved file so I restarting Blender doesn't do anything. If a setting changed, I don't know how it could do that on it's own with me not at the computer.
Does anyone have any knowledge of what causes this and how to fix it?

Go to sculpt mode and press Alt-A. Does a pie menu show up? That's the global automasking menu whose options, once checked/activated, don't change the automasking checkboxes in the tool tab.
Check if the you have any unwanted automasking options checked in that Alt-A pie menu, like the Cavity (inverted) one.
I just found this thread from looking up the problem as I've been dealing with it for YEARS, and I just found the solution.

